# What grade was the best batch of meth?

Tags: breaking-bad

What was the quality (*I believe it was percentage of pure product*) of the best batch made by Walt in Breaking Bad?

> In the latest episode, there is a complaint about the quality in the product produced by the people now cooking with Methylamine Walt was in possession of. I want to know just how drastic the quality drop was.

Comment: ok, I'm confused here. Why is this question off-topic? It's based on factual information pertaining to the Tv series.

Comment: @kicker86 taken from the FAQ, off topic questions include "Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title."

Comment: I'd argue this isn't trivia at all; the answer below demonstrates why the purity is crucial at certain moments; additionally, the premiere of the 2nd half of the final season demonstrates that the purity of the product will continue to be a plot point, as Lydia is upset that, with Walt retired, the purity of the product dropped to 68%, and Walt seems very disturbed by this.

Comment: @ColinD Are you sure that your edit is still the original question and what the OP really wants to know and not completely your own question? Likewise isn't it a good idea to hide the actual question inside a spoiler block.

Comment: @ChristianRau I already got my answer, and I'm okay with that edit. Essentially the answer to this "new" question will still get me my answer, but now it's just a better question :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best I can do based on memory and a bit of research are two examples of the purity mentioned in the show:

1) In a flashback scene at the start of Season 4, episode 1 titled "Box Cutter", Gale tells Gus that his product is 96% pure, but that whomever makes the "blue stuff" has achieved a purity of 99%.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1683084/synopsis

2) In the opening scene to the Season 5, episode 7 episode titled "Say My Name", Walter specifically states that his product is 99.1% pure compared to the other group's 70% purity.

http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad#Say_My_Name_.5B5.07.5D

As such, the highest quality I can recall being referenced specifically is **99.1%**.

Comment: The only other time I can think of that they mention the purity of his recipe would be when Gus took Jesse to Mexico. I do not recall if they mention the purity but Walt isn't there so it is not entirely relevant either.

Comment: @ColinD That purity only reached 96% IIRC

Comment: I believe Tyler is correct. Jesse produced a really good product, enough to please the cartel, but it was still a little behind what Walter can produce.

Comment: Just found that moment in the S04E10 where they're measuring the purity with a special machine, its red letters said it was **96.2%**, but basically it was made by Jessie and the cartel.

Comment: *"Walter specifically states that his product is 99.1% pure"*  That figure is also echoed by Hank when he talks to his team about the meth produced by Heisenberg.  I'm not sure if he'd connected that name to Walt at that early stage, but clearly recall him saying the meth was 99.1% pure - hence the DEA's interest in what had been a minor street bust.